# Why does setting ctypes dll.function.restype=c_void_p return long?

Tags: python, ctypes

It seems odd that even after setting `restype`, python returns `long` rather than `c_void_p`.

For example;

```
# python code
from ctypes import *
dll = windll.LoadLibrary("my.dll")
dll.my_object_create.restype = c_void_p
x = dll.my_object_create()
print type(x) # prints <type 'long'>

//c++ code
my_object *my_object_create() { return new my_object(); }
void my_object_destroy(my_object *obj) { delete obj; }
```

I recently had to fix a bug where, feeding `x` back to another ctypes function, the pointer got trampled.  This was fixed by changing the initial dll call to

```
x = c_void_p(dll.my_object_create())
```

...I'm guessing somewhere along the line ctypes treated `x` as 4 bytes long not 8 (64 bit architecture).

So I am wondering if there is a reason why the existing behaviour leads you into this trap?

Comment: This is an intended behavior. If restype is a simple ctypes type (`c_int`, `c_void_p`), `ctypes` will call the type's `getfunc`, but not the restype. See http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c#l899.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`P_get`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Modules/_ctypes/cfield.c#l1580) for the ['P' pointer type](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Modules/_ctypes/cfield.c#l1590) uses [`PyLong_FromVoidPtr`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/long.html#PyLong_FromVoidPtr). If the address fits in a platform `long`, it returns a Python `int`; otherwise it returns a Python `long`, which has variable precision. That's fine, but when passing this integer value as an argument, the default behavior is to [convert to a C `int`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c#l563), which is 32-bit on all supported platforms.

I think the best solution is to set `argtypes` to properly convert an argument to a pointer type. Another option is to set `restype` to a subclass of `c_void_p`. Using a subclass disables the conversion to a Python integer. [`GetResult`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c#l903) checks this by calling [`_ctypes_simple_instance`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#l2861), which actually returns the opposite of what its name and the source comment suggest. (In 2.5 this function was named [`IsSimpleSubType`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c10a71cf16e4/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#l2284), and the source comment was wrong back then too. The "simple" in question was never the metaclass [`PyCSimpleType`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#l2185), but the base type [`_SimpleCData`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#l4898).)

**POSIX:**

```python
# Configure the interpreter to load visible extension-
# module symbols, such as _ctypes_simple_instance, 
# into the global symbol table.
import sys, DLFCN
sys.setdlopenflags((sys.getdlopenflags() & ~DLFCN.RTLD_LOCAL) |
                   DLFCN.RTLD_GLOBAL)
from ctypes import *

_ctypes_simple_instance = PyDLL(None)._ctypes_simple_instance
_ctypes_simple_instance.argtypes = py_object,
malloc = CDLL(None).malloc

class my_void_p(c_void_p): 
    pass
```

```
>>> _ctypes_simple_instance(c_void_p)
0
>>> _ctypes_simple_instance(my_void_p)
1

>>> malloc.restype = c_void_p
>>> type(malloc(100))
<type 'int'>
>>> malloc.restype = my_void_p
>>> type(malloc(100))
<class '__main__.my_void_p'>
```

**Windows:**

`_ctypes_simple_instance` isn't exported by _ctypes.pyd.

```python
from ctypes import *

malloc = cdll.msvcrt.malloc

class my_void_p(c_void_p): 
    pass
```

```
>>> malloc.restype = c_void_p
>>> type(malloc(100))          
<class 'int'>
>>> malloc.restype = my_void_p
>>> type(malloc(100))         
<class '__main__.my_void_p'>
```