# Why does Python 2.7 sign extend HDC returned from GetDC() on x64?

Tags: python, 64-bit, windows-7-x64, cython

On Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] why is the return value of **GetDC()** sign extended?

```
from ctypes import *
hDC1 = windll.user32.GetDC(None)
print hex(hDC1), hDC1, type(hDC1)
hDC2 = windll.user32.GetDC(None)
print hex(hDC2), hDC2, type(hDC2)
```

Which will sometimes result in negative return values:

```
 0x6a0116c1  1778456257 <type 'int'>   # OK
-0x53fed994 -1409210772 <type 'int'>   # Why negative?
```

I believe HANDLES returned by GetDC() always fit within 32bits (even on x64), but cython seems to be sign extending the latter GetDC() return value if the highest bit in the 32 bit value is set (about 50% of the time).  Later, attempting to use this negative value HANDLE fails in subsequent GDI calls.

This seems like such a major issue, that I can't understand what I'm missing.

**Edit**:

This post seems to get to the root of the issue: [Why does setting ctypes dll.function.restype=c_void_p return long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840144/why-does-setting-ctypes-dll-function-restype-c-void-p-return-long)

In our case, adding:

```
class c_void_p(c_void_p): 
pass
```

to the beginning of the module where restype is defined for each GDI library function seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ctypes assumes that a function returns a signed int unless you tell it otherwise. Set the function *restype* to an unsigned value:

```
from ctypes import *
windll.user32.GetDC.restype = c_void_p
hDC1 = windll.user32.GetDC(None)
```

ctypes doesn't know anything about parameters and return values, just the entry point of the function. It takes a guess but lets you override with *argtypes* and *restype*.

Comment: in cython, we find

    HANDLE = ctypes.c_void_p 
    HDC = HANDLE

But Pyglet implements GetDC() which is in
pyglet/ libs/ win32/ __init__.py

    _user32.GetDC.restype = HDC
    _user32.GetDC.argtypes = [HWND] 

So whose bug is this?

Comment: Ah yes, it's been too long since I've used handles (Microsoft defines them as PVOID). I tried `c_void_p` and it worked for me so I'll change the answer. The pyglet definition should work too. Are you using GetDC before pyglet initializes the restype?

Comment: In the Microsoft data types world, HANDLE is a PVOID and both HDC and HWND are HANDLES. The pyglet definition looks correct to me (HWND goes in, HDC comes out).

Comment: Agree, the Pyglet definition looks right, which is why I'm so confused.  The hDC in Pyglet still comes back sign extended!

Comment: Strange indeed. Maybe some other module messes it up. It would be interesting to sprinkle some `print windll.user32.GetDC.restype` statements around.